# Rotate with SpaceMouse after choosing view with keyboard

Tags: 3d-view, navigation, 3dconnexion

I'm currently using Blender 4.0 with latest SpaceMouse driver on Windows 11. I have set the SpaceMouse up to my preferences in Blender, and it generally works as expected. However, I find that if I select a view using the numeric keyboard (e.g. 1 for front view), although I can pan and zoom, I am unable to rotate the view with the SpaceMouse until I first rotate with MMB or keyboard (e.g. <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>) or select perspective view.

Double-tapping numpad 5 does not enable rotation with SpaceMouse.

Has anyone else experienced similar? Is this a bug or feature, and is the issue with Blender or 3DConnexion?

I cannot find any setting in either Blender or 3DConnexion software to modify this behaviour.